Not Receiving All Expected Data When Doing Outer Join
I apologize ahead of time, I'm sure everyone is tired of join issues. This one is making me feel dumb because it's really underlining that I clearly don't understand joins the way I should.
The quick summary is I'm trying to get a result of 3 columns (hospital name, hold type, count of the # of holds) for all of our hospitals, and I want each hospital to always show for each of the 3 metrics I'm looking for, even if they don't have a record.
What I want to see is:
|hospital|  intervention|   intervention_cnt|
|-|-|-|
|First Hospital|    Physical Restraint| 72|
|First Hospital|    Seclusion|  NULL|
|First Hospital|    Mechanical Restraint|   NULL|
|Second Hospital|   Physical Restraint| 14|
|Second Hospital|   Seclusion|  3|
|Second Hospital|   Mechanical Restraint|   1|
But what I am getting is:
|hospital|  intervention|   intervention_cnt|
|-|-|-|
|First Hospital|    Physical Restraint| 72|
|Second Hospital|   Physical Restraint| 14|
|Second Hospital|   Seclusion|  3|
|Second Hospital|   Mechanical Restraint|   1|
And I'm sure there is a much better way than the way I'm doing it (i.e. the temp tables) but that is a problem for another day =).
The temp table holds only 3 records, the name of the holds you can see in the case statement.
I've tried various versions of the joins but can't quit get it right. Here is the one I THOUGHT was going to do the trick.
CREATE TABLE #interventions (
  intervention      varchar(100)
)

-- Populate #interventions.
INSERT INTO #interventions SELECT DISTINCT intervention FROM tblHolds WHERE intervention NOT LIKE '%@%' AND intervention <> 'Physical Hold'

-- Final query.
SELECT hosp_name AS hospital, a.intervention, COUNT(b.intervention) AS intervention_cnt
FROM #interventions a 
  LEFT JOIN tblHolds b ON a.intervention = b.intervention
  INNER JOIN tblHospitalList c ON b.hosp_id = c.hosp_id
GROUP BY hosp_name, a.intervention
ORDER BY hosp_name,
  CASE
    when a.intervention = 'Physical Restraint' THEN 1
    when a.intervention = 'Seclusion' THEN 2
    when a.intervention = 'Mechanical Restraint' THEN 3
    ELSE 9
END


DROP TABLE #interventions


Please read How To Create An Example and Why should I not upload images

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/mqbO0NS1

This might be solved using a cross join to get every combination of hospital and intervention.
SELECT hosp_name AS hospital, a.intervention, COUNT(b.intervention) AS intervention_cnt
FROM #interventions a 
  CROSS JOIN tblHospitalList c
  LEFT JOIN tblHolds b ON a.intervention = b.intervention AND  b.hosp_id = c.hosp_id
GROUP BY hosp_name, a.intervention
ORDER BY hosp_name,
  CASE a.intervention
    when 'Physical Restraint' THEN 1
    when 'Seclusion' THEN 2
    when 'Mechanical Restraint' THEN 3
    ELSE 9
END

fiddle



hospital
intervention
intervention_cnt




First Hospital
Physical Restraint
1


First Hospital
Seclusion
0


First Hospital
Mechanical Restraint
0


Second Hospital
Physical Restraint
1


Second Hospital
Seclusion
1


Second Hospital
Mechanical Restraint
1




@Jonas Metzler Good suggestion. Answer updated.

Awesome! I am not familiar with cross joins but that did the trick and I will read up on them this evening.
Also a great tip, Bart, about the CASE statement. I didn't know you could write them that way. I also note your post about some guidelines for posting, I'll check those out. This is my first post so I didn't realize how I formatted was a faux pas!
Much appreciation to the both of you!
